# Vim empty lines after quit

Tags: vim, terminal, command

I have the following line in my `vimrc`:

`silent !mkdir ~/.vim/.backup >/dev/null 2>&1`

If I open new terminal and open something with vim and then quit vim, some empty lines are inserted till the end of my terminal window, so the prompt becomes the last line in the terminal.

I'm using iTerm and OS X, but i tried the same thing on ubuntu and it behaves just the same.
I also tried running vim without plugins, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in the described above command. If I comment it, everything works fine.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

My vim version is:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jul 10 2015 04:05:27)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `mkdir()` function instead of calling the shell command.

```
if !isdirectory($HOME . '/.vim/.backup')
    call mkdir($HOME . '/.vim/.backup', 'p')
endif
```

The check `isdirectory` is needed since `mkdir()` errors if the directory already exists.